# Three Events Problem Interpretation

Tags: probability, self-study

So I am having trouble understanding what this problem is asking. (I am not asking someone to solve it but simply help interpret what the problem wants me to do.)

The problem goes like this:

> "Let $A$, $B$, and $C$ be three events.  Show that exactly two of these events will occur with probability $P(AB) + P(AC) + P(BC) - 3P(ABC)$."

What I do not understand is that am I supposed to show that $P(A) + P(B) = P(AB) + P(AC) + P(BC) - 3P(ABC)$ or $P(A) + P(C) = $ SAME THING or $P(AC) = $ SAME THING or etc.  I guess what is throwing me off is the "exactly two events will occur" part.

I was able to show that $P(AB) + P(AC) + P(BC) - 3P(ABC) = P(ABC^c) + P(ACB^c) + P(BCA^c)$
and if this is NOT what I was supposed to do then I am completely lost.

Comment: You should most-definitely add a `self-study` tag to this question. You can do so by clicking the "edit" button at the lower left of your question.

Comment: Have you learned about [Venn diagrams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venn_diagram)? Drawing one might help you make reasonable guesses concerning the intended interpretation of this question.

Comment: Hint: the events $ABC^c$, $AB^cC$, and $A^cBC$ are _mutually exclusive_ or _disjoint_. Can you prove this? If so, apply the third axiom of probability to deduce that $$P(ABC^c \cup AB^cC\cup A^cBC) = PABC^c)+ P(AB^cC) + P(A^cBC)$$ where the left-hand side is the probability of the event that _exactly_ two events occurred (which implied that the third did not) and so it must be the case that $A$ and $B$ occurred but $C$ did not, or $A$ and $C$ occurred but $B$ did not, or $B$ and $C$ occurred but $A$ did not.

Comment: Do you see that your last expression on the right hand side is all the 'exactly two' events? If so, Dilip's comment should get you all the rest of the way.